# Notation when finding critical points of a function with derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we want to find out the critical points of a function (for example the vertices of a quadratic function $ax^2+bx+c$), can we write $$\frac{d}{dx} (ax^2+bx+c)=0$$
or do we have to clearly show that the variables are different by writing $$\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2+bx+c)|_{\substack{x=x_1}}=0 \\
2ax_1+b=0 \\
x_1=-\frac{b}{2a}$$
Where $x_1$ is the x-coordinate of the vertex?

Comment: The first case is well-understood (provided you put parentheses).  You're right that it's a small abuse of notation, but everyone will understand.

Comment: You could use some parentheses there, I think. I would read the $d/dx$ as applying only to the first term.